# How do i prevent players from spamming move messages (Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, network-programming, p5.js

Essentially, i want to learn of the industry standard, and proper practices of preventing players from spamming movement packets.

To demonstrate my current dilemma, i have made a 1-dimensional example, using the key concepts from https://www.gabrielgambetta.com/client-server-game-architecture.html except for interpolation. As such, my movement messages consist of the direction (-1 or 1) and the client's timestamp (used for reconciliation).

```
// Client move function, dir = -1 or 1
function move (dir, dt) {
    localxPos += dir;
    last_ts_local = Date.now();

    socket.emit('move', {
        ts: last_ts_local,
        dir: dir
    });
}
```

Since the server simply adds the direction to the players position for EVERY movement packet sent, a flurry of movement messages can be sent to move faster.

```
 ...

// Server receive move
socket.on('move', function(msg) {
        clients[socket.id].process_queue_moves.push(msg);
});

 ...

// Server processes movement queue (run every 1 seconds - very slow for example purposes)
for (var i = 0; i < clientIDs.length; i++) {
      clientID = clientIDs[i];

      // process movement queue
      for (var j = 0; j < clients[clientID].process_queue_moves.length; j++) {
          clients[clientID].xPos += (clients[clientID].process_queue_moves[j].dir)/Math.abs(clients[clientID].process_queue_moves[j].dir);
      }
      if (clients[clientID].process_queue_moves.length > 0) {
          clients[clientID].last_ts = clients[clientID].process_queue_moves[clients[clientID].process_queue_moves.length-1].ts;
      } else {
          clients[clientID].last_ts == -1;
      }
      // clear movement queue
      clients[clientID].process_queue_moves = [];

}
```

I initially thought that i could base the client's framerate - or packet rate on the amount of packets they send. However, i quickly realised that if a client sends 2 packets out, it doesn't mean they have 2 FPS. They could simply be standing still, and moved for 2 frames.

After this realisation, i discovered that i could send the move packet even when the player is not moving - more like an input packet. This way, the client could send the move message with a direction of 0 when not moving.

This eliminates the malicious potential for players, since, if the player sends 1000 packets, the server can infer that the player simply has 1000 FPS, and limit the movement as such.

Now, i'm not sure if this is the best way to handle this, or if sending a message every frame is too intensive. If there is a better way to do this, could you please let me know :).

Thanks

Comment: you should only send packets when information changes.

Comment: one way to handle the whole thing is to throttle the number of packets they send and provide a x coordinate instead tracking every single movement. If your threshold is too low then the movements will appear choppy unless you interpolate the movements from last known position to new position.

Comment: if you're keeping track of the player's fps on their own device, include that info with each packet that is sent to the server.... never try to infer or guess their fps based on number of packets you are receiving

Comment: the limit a player can move should never be based on their FPS. it should be based on distance over time. players with more fps should not be allowed to move further faster. the client should limit movements to distance over time and your server should validate each player's movements in distance over time to ensure nothing nefarious is going on.

Comment: The amount that the player is able to move PER FRAME should be dependant on their FPS, or some rate at which the position is updated. Also, requesting the FPS from the player to validate their movements is a questionable solution, and the request can be intercepted and changed.

Comment: you shouldn't care what their fps is actually. you move them a fixed amount over time and the FPS being completely separate just draws the position as it can. and if any decisions need to be made based on FPS, you can't guess what their FPS is. the device has to send it. if security needs to be incorporated to protect that information then so be it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by sending fragments of input (to keep the packets down - i have it at 20 tps). The input packets also contain when the player is not moving to perform accurate validation. If you'd like to know more info on how i solved this, pm me :).